# return message from old way AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

I have two pages, one page is HTML that perform to request data to second page by using old way AJAX.

Here, I add a new record to the database and return it like this:

```
var HttPRequest = false;

function doCallAjax(Mode, Page, ID) {
    HttPRequest = false;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari,...
        HttPRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        if (HttPRequest.overrideMimeType) {
            HttPRequest.overrideMimeType('text/html');
        }
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE
        try {
            HttPRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try {
                HttPRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {}
        }
    }

    if (!HttPRequest) {
        alert('Cannot create XMLHTTP instance');
        return false;
    }

    var url = 'AjaxItemsGroupsRecord.php';
    var pmeters = "titems_groups_GroupName=" + encodeURI(document.getElementById("items_groups_GroupName").value) +
        "&titems_groups_sys_type_ID=" + encodeURI(document.getElementById("items_groups_sys_type_ID").value) +
        '&myPage=' + Page +
        "&tID=" + ID +
        "&tMode=" + Mode;

    HttPRequest.open('POST', url, true);

    HttPRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    HttPRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-length", pmeters.length);
    HttPRequest.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
    HttPRequest.send(pmeters);


    HttPRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {

        if (HttPRequest.readyState == 3) // Loading Request
        {
            document.getElementById("mySpan").innerHTML = "Loading";
        }

        if (HttPRequest.readyState == 4) // Return Request
        {
            document.getElementById("mySpan").innerHTML = HttPRequest.responseText;
        }

    }

}
```

If I insert error, I need to return massage error on other div, I need only show error message, how can do it

I tried but it does not work yet

This is my PHP code:

```
if($strMode == "ADD")
{
$sql_setting="SELECT * FROM stores_items";
$sr=mysql_query($sql_setting);
$S=@mysql_fetch_array($sr);
$stores_items_Name=$S["stores_items_Name"];     
if($_POST["tstores_items_Name"]==$stores_items_Name){
echo $msg="<div class='gadget err_or'><div class='error_tit'>
<a rel='hide_err' class='hideerr' href='#'><img width='19' height='33' alt='picture' src='../images/spacer.gif'></a>
<a rel='close_err' class='closeerr' href='#'><img width='19' height='33' alt='picture' src='../images/spacer.gif'></a>
<h3>Message</h3>
</div>
<div class='error_msg'><p>its founded</p></div>
</div>";            
}   
elseif($_POST["tstores_items_Name"]=="" or $_POST["tstores_items_SalePrice_By_Store"]=="" or $_POST["tstores_items_BuyPrice_By_Store"]==""){
echo $msg="<div class='gadget err_or'><div class='error_tit'>
<a rel='hide_err' class='hideerr' href='#'><img width='19' height='33' alt='picture' src='../images/spacer.gif'></a>
<a rel='close_err' class='closeerr' href='#'><img width='19' height='33' alt='picture' src='../images/spacer.gif'></a>
<h3>Message</h3>
</div>
<div class='error_msg'><p>(*) Fill </p></div></div>";           
}
else
{   
    $stores_items_AddDate=date('Y/m/d');
    $strSQL = "INSERT INTO stores_items ";
    $strSQL .="(stores_items_ID,stores_items_Name,stores_items_GroupId,stores_items_Barcode,stores_items_SalePrice_By_Store,stores_items_BuyPrice_By_Store,stores_items_Unit,stores_items_Currency,stores_items_Type,stores_items_AddType,stores_items_AddUser,stores_items_AddDate,stores_items_Delete,stores_items_StoreId,stores_items_sys_type_ID) ";
    $strSQL .="VALUES ";
    $strSQL .="('' , '".clean($_POST["tstores_items_Name"])."' , '".clean($_POST["tstores_items_GroupId"])."' , '".clean($_POST["tstores_items_Barcode"])."' , '".clean($_POST["tstores_items_SalePrice_By_Store"])."' ,'".clean($_POST["tstores_items_BuyPrice_By_Store"])."','".clean($_POST["tstores_items_Unit"])."','".clean($_POST["tstores_items_Currency"])."','".clean($_POST["tstores_items_Type"])."','1','$ausers_ID','$stores_items_AddDate' , '0','$ausers_StoreId','".clean($_POST["tstores_items_sys_type_ID"])."') ";
    $objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);
echo $msg="<div class='gadget err_bl'><div class='error_tit'>
<a rel='hide_err' class='hideerr' href='#'><img width='19' height='33' alt='picture' src='../images/spacer.gif'></a>
<a rel='close_err' class='closeerr' href='#'><img width='19' height='33' alt='picture' src='../images/spacer.gif'></a>
<h3>Message</h3>
</div>
<div class='error_msg'><p>Done</p></div></div>";
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to return a complex result is to output a JSON encoded array on the PHP side:

```
$output = array('result' => false, 'message' => '');

// do your insert, then set $output['result'] = true if successful
// also set the message as required in $output['message'] = 'Success!'

echo json_encode($output);
```

Using that, you can return a boolean to say if it was successful, and also a message.

On the Javascript side, you can decode the JSON and check the result:

```
if(HttPRequest.readyState == 4) // Return Request
{
    var obj = JSON.parse(HttPRequest.responseText);

    if(obj.result)
    {
        // success, do something or use obj.message
        console.log( "success: " + obj.message );
    }
    else
    {
        // fail -do something
        console.log( "fail: " + obj.message );
    }
}
```

Comment: where can i defint this `$output = array('result' => false, 'message' => '');

// do your insert, then set $output['result'] = true if successful
// also set the message as required in $output['message'] = 'Success!'

echo json_encode($output);`

Comment: Define it in the PHP code that the ajax calls. It allows you to tell the ajax if it was successful, and give it a message to display.

Comment: Does the PHP echo the correct html? Try calling it directly from the browser.

Comment: yes, it echo correct, are you need css style and all pages ??

Comment: If you are echoing the divs from PHP, why not just echo an error div in the event of an error?

Comment: mmm i think i define $output in not place ?? can you edit in my code to show problem

Comment: Because you are echoing the whole divs, there wouldn't be much benefit to using the JSON solution. Just echo an error div as needed?